# Prebid doesn't recognize CMP

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I'm trying to setup Prebid to send a GDPR consent value to SSPs. I've implemented CMP but in console I can see that Prebid just ignores it

> WARNING: CMP not found. Resuming auction without consent data as per
>   consentManagement config. undefined

I've no idea why Prebid doesn't recognize CMP, it is IAB compliant so everything should be ok. Any ideas where I made mistake?

Edit: The problem is I implemented setup from prebid.org to my site

```
        pbjs.que.push(function() {
          pbjs.setConfig({
      consentManagement: {
        cmpApi: 'iab',
        timeout: 5000,
        allowAuctionWithoutConsent: true
      }
    });
```

Also made a change to prebid.js file which now contains consentManagement adapter.

script type="text/javascript" src="http://testowa.epizy.com/prebid2.9.0.js" async>

I built a digi-trust cmp from https://github.com/adform/cmp and also implemented it on my site.

Everything looks ok, CMP works fine, I get an consent and I can see it in my console. However Prebid dosen't see that there is an CMP and it throws out a warning with an information I've mentioned before.

So even though I get consent and see cookie the request for an ad goes without it because prebid doesn't recognize it.

I need that consent to go with an ad request to SSPs.

Hope I made it a bit easier to understand what my problem is. I could provide a test page if needed.

Comment: FWIW, this seems to happen with Google's Funding Choices CMP too, at least since TCFv2. But the below fix of sending cookie value manually seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason it doesn't recognise the cookie, a possible fix is just to send the cookie as static:

```
{
  cmpApi: 'static',
  timeout: 5000,
  allowAuctionWithoutConsent: true,
  consentData: {
    getConsentData: {
      gdprApplies: true,
      hasGlobalScope: false,
      consentData: 'COOKIE CONTENT'
    },
    getVendorConsents: {
      metadata: 'COOKIE CONTENT',
      gdprApplies: true
    }
  }
}
```

This way you would send the whole cookie so it should work, but note that you need all attributes I mention above (prebid issues not related to this). Make sure you validate the cookie though, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I got it working when I loaded the CMP script synchronously before prebid.js library, with the consent management module included.

also changed:
allowAuctionWithoutConsent: false

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't implemented the __cmp stub function. This is what should happen on your page:

- Define the window.__cmp() function (inline or synchronously)
- Load the CMP (cmp.bundle.js) asynchronously which replaces window.__cmp() with the actual CMP.
- Load Prebid asynchronously

Prebid.js calls __cmp().ping() to see if the real __cmp() has been loaded. If __cmp() doesn't exist at all it just assumes that you haven't implemented a CMP and goes ahead with the auction.

Check out the 'Setup Script' chapter of the DigiTrust CMP documentation. The required code is also here:
https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/CMP%20JS%20API%20v1.1%20Final.md#CMP-stub-sample